# Showing validation errors next to its field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any way to show errors not on top of form page, but next to field, that fired an error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**initializers/my_custom_error_messages.rb**

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  errors = Array(instance.error_message).join(',')
  %(#{html_tag}<span class="validation-error">&nbsp;#{errors}</span>).html_safe
end
```

**update:**

without label

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  errors = Array(instance.error_message).join(',')

  if html_tag =~ /^<label/
    html_tag
  else
    %(#{html_tag}<span class="validation-error">&nbsp;#{errors}</span>).html_safe
  end

end
```

ref: [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#customizing-the-error-messages-html)

Comment: this way actually adds error messages not just to inputs but to labels aswell

Comment: is there any way to ignore f.label fields and apply errors only to input fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple_form gem to show the validation error with the fields

```
   <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
       <%= f.input :username %>
       <%= f.input :password %>
       <%= f.button :submit %>
   <% end %>
```

And if you want to show the validation error on the top of form use

```
    object.error_messages
```

After form tag

Answer (score 1):

This used to be part of Rails, now it's available in a gem:

https://github.com/joelmoss/dynamic_form

It allows you to easily display the errors for any particular attribute of a form builder object, for example:

```
<%= f.text_field :foo %>
<%= f.error_message_on :foo %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors are displayed on the top of your form because of the `@model.errors` iteration in the top div of your layout. If you move this code to check for errors on your hash on each field, you can acomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="error"><%=@user.errors[:firstname].join(",") %></td>
```

Comment: errors[] is an error array to deal with any errror during the validation. we can specify errors[:object name] will display the error related to particular object. for ex:

Comment: You should [edit] your post to include the code that the comment ate.